# HTTP Error in WordPress media upload NGINX+Apache

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

I am using a server that has Apache with NGINX as proxy server, now I am facing an issue with image uploading in WordPress, sometimes WordPress giving HTTP Error.

My PHP upload and post limit is 50MB, NGINX client max body size is 100MB, WP memory limit 256MB, PHP Memory Limit 256MB

Can anyone please help me where and what else I have to check?

Comment: Can you have a log file to show us ?

Comment: What's the full error message? Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi Paul, I checked and I don't find any recent error log entry, all are few days old but I am facing this issue today after setup this server a few days ago.

Comment: Hi Aynber, not anything else just showing HTTP Error. within image upload section

Comment: Please check this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/HkUKxxb.png